# Statistical test for testing different between groups in terms of efficiency in regression

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, t-test, chi-squared-test, mcnemar-test

During my thesis work I collected some measurements about chest compressions that reached a good depth (binomial data) during cardiopulmonary rescuscitaion (CPR), I have two groupes of volunteers and each volunteer performed a number unequal of chest compressions with the use or not of a device.

In other word,I have two sessions (with and without the use of a device) and two groups of volunteers that perform different compressions within a minute.

So, what I need is to compare the difference between the two groups in term of efficiency? Which test should I apply to compare binomial data between the two groups?